# Why should I use connection pooling?

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, connection-pooling

In my C# application I connect to a `MySQL` database and run 10,000 queries. If I keep a connection to my database, these queries take roughly 14 seconds. However, if I rely on the connection pooling my queries take around 15 seconds. (I have run this test multiple times.)

```
// Connection pooling.
using (var connection = CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();
```

Most samples on the net make use of the 'connect and close' construction above. However, it seems connection pooling is slower than keeping the connection. So the question is...

**Q:** Why should I use connection pooling?

Comment: I don't understand, 14 seconds is faster than 15 seconds, isn't it?

Comment: You just said that with connection pooling your queries take 14 instad of 15 seconds. How is that "slower"?

Comment: Er, 14 seconds < 15 seconds. Probably a typo...

Comment: 1s over 15 is barely anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a big debatable topic and would find many blog out there would tell that why we use Pool.

It will not slow things down. There is a lot of time spend on Connecting to DB Server and Hand shake and establishing communication between client and DB server.

So in multi request paradigm where many request are entertained by the server, it would be hard to establish and put on wait each client. POOL helps us that it gives us pre prepared connection and we use it and discard it. POOL get that connection and re-establish it for the next request.

But in a single threaded environment it is the other way around. POOL would be a very heavy resource for a single threaded env.

Comment: I think your last sentence nails it.

Answer (score 6):

> Q: Why should I use connection pooling?

Usually so that you can use more than one connection at a time. This is clearly important for web applications - you wouldn't want one user query to have to wait for another user's query to finish.

If you're writing a thick client application which talks straight to the database and you know you'll only ever have one query executing at a time, it's *less* important - but it's still global state, and that tends to be something you should avoid. You're doing several independent things - why would you *want* to constrain them to use the same connection?

Comment: If you have 2 users on a website, wouldn't they both get their own thread, and if that thread opens a connections to the database, wouldn't they both get a new connection regardless of connection pooling? Can you explain why one would be have to wait for the other user's query to finish?

Comment: @Greg: The OP talks about: "If I keep a connection to my database, these queries take roughly 14 seconds." In other words, *not* creating a connection per request, but keeping a *single* connection for the whole application. They could potentially use a single open connection per thread, but in modern web frameworks I wouldn't assume that a request executes on a single thread for the whole time either, given asynchronous operations...

Answer (score 4):

Connection pooling is great for scalability - if you have 100 threads/clients/end-users, each of which need to talk to the database, you don't want them all to have a dedicated connection open to the database (connections are expensive resources), but rather to share connections (via pooling).

The using mini-pattern is also great for ensuring the connection is closed in a timely fashion which will end any transactions on the connection and thus ensure any locks taken by the transactions are released. This can be a great help for performance, and for minimising the potential for deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

If all your application does is run the 10,000 queries and then close again without any user interaction then it's fine to use one single connection.

However it's generally not a good idea to keep a database connection open while your application is just sitting there waiting for user input. This is where connection pooling is appropriate.

Pseudo code ...

```
<open connection>
<fetch data>
<close connection>

<user interaction with data ...>

<open connection>
<save updated data>
<close connection>
```

Depending on the language / database used, the second connection will be generated from the connection pool.